# Automate the webcam to take a picture

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What would a code snippet be for Visual Basic 2010 to automate the webcam to click a picture based on if any key is pressed on the keyboard?

Comment: Are you trying to write a program that will see who tries to log into your machine while it's locked?

Comment: Something similar,but using a motion sensor to detect an intruder, when the intruder is detected , the webcam takes a picture and then locks the system completely including the incoming and outgoing internet traffic.I'm done with all the other modules, but haven't "handled" webcams, so thought I'll post a question here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There's an [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/wiascriptingdotnet.aspx) that you might find useful.

Comment: tough to relate to, considering that I want something is visual-basic.I'm kinda new to vb, so a vb article will help.